# Uncaught TypeError is not a function when I call a method from another method using setInterval in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having this error when I call a method from another method in a class. This method is been called from setInterval.

```
class App {
    b() {
        console.log("BBBBBBBB")
    }

    t() {
        console.log("TTTTTTT")
        this.b();
    }
}


const t = new App();


setInterval(t.t, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind the method to the variable so the value of `this` stays constant. Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) page for more information.

```js
setInterval(t.t.bind(t), 1000);
```

Comment: This solves the problem. I need 8 min. to accept the answer. :)